# How can i put the objects in an array under each other instead of next to each other?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, parse-platform, sass

i just need to show the role content so tha array under each other instead of next to each other on a line or i need to have a scrolling option in that part of the td so it scrolls horizontal [image]

```
<tr ng-repeat="companyUser in companyUsers | filter:search | orderBy:sort">
    <td>
        <nobr>{{companyUser.user.firstName}}</nobr>
    </td>
    <td>
        <nobr>{{companyUser.user.lastName}}</nobr>
    </td>
    <td>
        <nobr>{{companyUser.user.username}}</nobr>
    </td>
    <td>
        <nobr>{{companyUser.user.role}}</nobr>
    </td> </tr>
```

I use Parse to load the data with Parse and a Parse database, But the main thing is that i want the role td to be horizontal scrollable or under eac other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `ng-repeat` over the person's roles in your `<td>` tag.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = [
    {
      firstname: "User",
      lastname: "Lastname",
      email: "email@email.com",
      role: ["Role1", "Role2", "Role3", "Role4"] 
    },
    {
      firstname: "User2",
      lastname: "Lastname2",
      email: "email2@email2.com",
      role: ["Role1", "Role2", "Role3", "Role4"] 
    }
  ]
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.0" data-semver="1.6.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>First name</th>
        <th>Last name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Roles</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="person in data">
        <td>{{person.firstname}}</td>
        <td>{{person.lastname}}</td>
        <td>{{person.email}}</td>
        <td><div ng-repeat="role in person.role">{{role}}</div></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```